# React Native - Unable to resolve module XYZ

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

I created my first [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) app with the following commands.

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-ios
```

I installed [react-native-material-design](https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design) and simply added

```
import { Button, Card } from 'react-native-material-design';
```

in my `index.ios.js` file. I get the following error.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Try closing your react packager in the command line & debugger, then do`react-native run-ios` again.

Comment: Awesome. Matt, can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: glad that worked! Just posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you add a new library you have to close your react packager in the command line & debugger, then do `react-native run-ios` again.

Answer (score 0):

If it need some linking with the native module then run rnpm link from your home directory and close your server, to restart the server use `npm install` or `react-native start` or `react-native run-ios` if using iOS device.

If no linking then you should run the command to integrate server only.

Cheers:)